# Setup XBee (serial) network

Tags: xbee

I want to setup an xBee network with four serial 1 modules. Any two of them can communicate with each other in two-way. The transmitted data is string other than a single byte.

My original design is to setup a nonbeacon (with coordinator) network: One module is configured as coordinator. The left three modules is configured as end devices. The coordinator broadcasts the data from end devices.

The communication workflow is: If end device 1 want to send data to end device 2, it sends data to coordinator first. Then the coordinator broadcasts the data received from end device 1. End device 2 can receive the broadcast data. The communication workflow finishes.

I want the received string to be atomic. If end device 1 and end device 3 send out the data in the same time, there would be conflict. The two strings would combined together. And the end device 2 can't distinguish which byte is from which device. That is, end device 1 sends out string "{AAAA}" (quotes aren't included). In the meanwhile, end device 3 sends out string "<2222>". The end device 2 may receive the string like "{A<22AA2A2}>", which isn't what I want. My expected string is "{AAAA}<2222>" or "<2222>{AAAA}".

How do I setup the network to meet my requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve atomic transmissions using Digi's XBee modules. The method varies depending on if API-mode (AP parameter > 0) is in use or not.

If API mode is not in use (AP = 0) then the atomicity of data can be encouraged by setting the RO time to be greater than the number of characters of the *longest string* you are going to send from one of your nodes.  This will make the XBee buffer wait the specified number of character times (the time it takes to send a character at a particular baud rate) before starting the over-the-air transmission.  Note: you'll have to ensure that you send your entire string all at once to the radio in order for this scheme to work.

If API mode is being used (AP > 0) then it is very easy to get the behavior you want.  You'll simply use the Tx Request frame (API frame type 0x1) and specify the string data you want to send.  The data will always be sent atomically.

If API mode is being used on the on the receiving node (i.e. in this case, the coordinator) then the frame data will always arrive atomically as well.

Please refer to the [Digi XBee 802.15.4 product support page](http://www.digi.com/support/productdetail?pid=3257) for more information on how to use API mode and search the Internet for the many wonderful XBee libraries which allow you to use Digi XBee modules in API mode easily.